# "Read-only filesystem" error during docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian, docker-buildkit

I was following the "Build with Docker" guide from the official documentation (https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/test/), which suggests that one can utilize bind mounts to generate files during the build of a Docker image and export them to the filesystem.

However, I am running into the following error:

```
[lint-base 2/2] RUN --mount=type=bind,target=.     echo "test" > lint-result:
0.258 /bin/sh: 1: cannot create lint-result: Read-only file system
...
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c echo \"test\" > lint-result" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

Here is the relevant part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch as lint-base
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=. \
    echo "test" > lint-result
```

And this was the command for building this layer:

```
docker build --output=. --target=lint-base -t lint-debug --progress=plain .
```

I'm using Debian, and Docker was installed using apt. The Docker version is `25.0.4`.

Is this permission issue stemming from the way I installed Docker, or is it normal that during docker builds, it is not allowed to write changes to the filesystem mounted by bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you use a bind mount in a Dockerfile, it still can't write out files to the host.

The Dockerfile [`RUN --mount=type=bind` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#run---mount) notes

> A bind mount is read-only by default.

which is consistent with the "read-only filesystem" error you're getting.  There is an additional option to make it read-write, but (emphasis mine)

> `rw`,`readwrite`: Allow writes on the mount. **Written data will be discarded.**

The [documentation page you link to](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/test/) does say you can export test results

> ...no different[ly from] exporting binaries, as shown in the previous section of this guide

More specifically the [Export binaries](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/export/) documentation suggests a `docker build --output=.` option that can use the Docker image builder but produce artifacts on the host by exporting the container filesystem.  If the image is built `FROM scratch` then "the container filesystem" will only include specific files you choose.  That also means the image doesn't contain any tools at all, so you have to construct the files in an earlier build stage and `COPY` them into the final image.

For your example this might look like:

```bash
FROM ubuntu AS build
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo test > lint-result

FROM scratch AS export
COPY --from=build /app/lint-result /
```

```bash
docker build --output=. --target=export .
```

I probably wouldn't use Docker here, but instead a shell script or Makefile to work with code and create files on the host.

Comment: Right, the only caveat is that this guide really means not to run the `echo test` command, but rather `golangci-lint`, with .go files from host system. I don't think it is possible to do using mount=bind, because obviously when you do that, there is no way to save the linter output in file anymore.

Still, based on your suggestion and by swapping `mount=bind,target=.` with `COPY . .`, I was successful with storing linter output in a file, and then by building another Image from scratch I was able to copy it to the host system. Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to run a tool on files that live on the host system, and write output to the host system, Docker's core isolation features work against you.  I wouldn't use Docker for this, and the image-build system seems like an especially poor match.